# Column separator in qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I'm making a survey in Qualtrics with a matrix table. I want to have six options across the top, with one of them separated from the rest by a vertical line (or alternatively, more white space). How can I do this? Concretely it would look like

(Hate) (Don't like) (Ambivalent) (like) (love) | (Don't know)

across the top, with the column separator extending down the matrix table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a web search on: Qualtrics Add Vertical Line Before Last Matrix Column